# How to make rectangle from 4 points in cocoa? for resizable rect

Tags: macos, cocoa, rect

How to make rectangle from 4 points? I'm creating resizable rectangle by the corners.

I can make it with two points like this:

```
NSMakeRect( MIN(point1.x, point3.x), 
                      MIN(point1.y, point3.y), 
                      fabs(point1.x - point3.x), 
                      fabs(point1.y - point3.y));
```

It's working good if I move 1 (left bottom) or 3 (right top) corner, but if 2 (left top) or 4 (right bottom) - not. How to make it with 4 NSPoints - corners?

Comment: Do you want to create a Rectangle or a Polygon?

Comment: @Tharabas I want to create rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers have produced you rectangles, but you say they don't do what you want but not why they are wrong... So I'll have a guess, just in case I guess right:

I'm guessing that you have a rectangle and you wish to move one of its corners as you might when click-dragging in a graphical program. I further assume based on your sample code that the rectangle sides are parallel to the axes.

In this scenario the point diagonally opposite the one you move is the anchor - it stays put. The one you move obviously moves, and the other two move to keep the shape rectangular.

If this is the case then you calculate the rectangle based solely on the point you move and its diagonally opposite point. The code you give in your question handles the case if point1 or point3 is moved. You just need a code for the case point2 or point4 is moved, which you get by simple substitution:

```
NSMakeRect( MIN(point2.x, point4.x), 
                  MIN(point2.y, point4.y), 
                  fabs(point2.x - point4.x), 
                  fabs(point2.y - point4.y));
```

You now just need to know which point you moved and select the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

To build a Rectangle that includes all of your given NSPoints - no matter how many - you'd have to find the *minimum* and *maximum* values.

```
// start by initializing their opposite MIN/MAX values
CGFloat xmin = CGFLOAT_MAX, xmax = CGFLOAT_MIN,
        ymin = CGFLOAT_MAX, ymax = CGFLOAT_MIN;
NSUInteger pointCount = ? // you'd have to add this
NSPoint points[pointCount] = { ... } // suppose you know your values :D

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
  xmin = MIN(xmin, points[i].x);
  xmax = MAX(xmax, points[i].x);
  ymin = MIN(ymin, points[i].y);
  ymax = MAX(ymax, points[i].y);
}

// now create a rect from those points
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin);
```

Comment: hmm.. this code makes rect but not what I need. Sorry I was said too less to understand correctly what I need. Your example draw rectangle by max point. I need that it will draw x,y. I'm creating resizable rectangle, so if I resize point it stays with another point. Thanks for help, but maybe You know how to solve this? I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem for you is points, check them.

Rectangle from 4 points you can draw like this:

```
NSMakeRect(MIN(MIN(points[0].x, points[2].x), MIN(points[1].x, points[3].x)),
           MIN(MIN(points[0].y, points[2].y), MIN(points[1].y, points[3].y)),
           MAX(fabs((points[0].x - points[2].x)),fabs(points[1].x - points[3].x)),
           MAX(fabs((points[0].y - points[2].y)), fabs((points[1].y - points[3].y))));
```